# ffmpeg - Copy audio channel but keep the same quality

Tags: audio, ffmpeg

I have a bunch of videos which have been recorded in stereo but the audio is present only on the left channel. I'm using this command to convert them:

```
find * -prune -name “*.mp4” -exec ffmpeg -n -i “{}” —c:a copy ac 1 “./final/{}” \;
```

This command seems to lower the files' size, and I'm glad since I don't need a perfect video, having the size so small is fine. However, **I need a perfect audio**, just the same quality as the original... just in both channels. With this command, the audio quality gets significantly worse. I wouldn't like to mess with options, I'd like to maintain just the exact same audio quality.

The command `-c:a copy` doesn't seem to work in combination with this command. How can I do it?

Thanks.

Edit: Here's the report: https://gist.github.com/UserGalileo/49bc8b7b85c05fe29bb044b6f599d71d

Comment: Add -report and run the command on one of the files. Share report.

Comment: @Gyan Added! thanks

Comment: It seems using ```-aq 0``` solves the problem, trying it right now